# Checking if provided String is a valid list of items

Tags: regex, groovy

I want to validate whether a String provided by the user forms a list of comma-separated items (ints, strings, mixed - doesn't matter) in Groovy. Two main requirements are that the list can't contain empty items and there should be no whitespace anywhere within. So sample valid Strings would be:

```
1,2,3
1,a,https://test
brown,fox,cat
EN,ES,XOO,ksSIj
test
?@)($,one,two
```

While invalid would be things like:

```
,,,
12,,34
a, b, c
```

What would be the best way of doing this in groovy? The only think I thought of was regex like `[^,]+` (though this one allows for whitespace characters. Any other possibilities or is tweaking this regex until it works the only way - and if so, what would be the least complex way of expressing this with regex?

Comment: If you want a regex, use `/^[^\s,]+(?:,[^\s,]+)*$/`. Use a slashy string in Groovy to define the regex in order to use a single backslash with regex escapes.

Comment: It seems that you need `^[^,\s]+(?:,[^\s,]+)*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - perfect, just what I need! Plus a very good remark about the slashy string, definitely helped me as I'm not that well-versed in Groovy. If you'd like to upgrade your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you may use here is

```
/^[^\s,]+(?:,[^\s,]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7U3BQR/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

In detail:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\s,]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and comma
- `(?:,[^\s,]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `,` - comma
  - `[^\s,]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and comma
- `$` - end of string.

Use a slashy string in Groovy to define the regex in order to use a single backslash with regex escapes.

Also, if you use `==~` operator, you do not even need `^` and `$` anchors as `==~` regex matching operator requires a full string match in Groovy:

```
def s = '1,a,https://test'
def regex = /[^\s,]+(?:,[^\s,]+)*/
print s ==~ regex
```

Output is `true`, or `false` if you add a comma at the end.

See [this Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/HhBaiQ).

If you have to use `=~` operator, keep the anchors:

```
def regex = /^[^\s,]+(?:,[^\s,]+)*$/
print s =~ regex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in groovy without regexes, which may be more legible:

```
boolean isInvalid(String str) {
    def split = str.split(',')
    str.contains(" ") || !split.size() || !split.every{it}
}
```

returns `true` if

- The input contains whitespace, or
- splitting on `,` results in an empty array, or
- Not every item in the resulting list after splitting is "truthy"